# Solr - complicated sort

Tags: solr

I need to sort a list of properties by the following:

1. Search Term (ex.  City:Atlanta)
2. Distance (ex. distance from center of Atlanta, Ga) : geodist(LatLng,34.002878,-84.144637) desc
3. PackageLevel asc
4. Random Order for PackageLevel's 1-5: product(map(PackageLevel, 1, 5, 1), seedrandom_10) desc
5. Distance:  geodist() asc

I can handle all but the first requirement.  I have tried termfreq(City, 'Atlanta'), but it returns an error:

> sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: termfreq(City,'Atlanta')

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

unless you are on 4.0 you dont have those functions available in 3.6...see [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg52368.html)